# Matlab error: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 131072x1, op2 is 128000x1)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I'm trying to multiply two vectors in my matlab code. But in this line,

```
fHatNoisy  = indices.*fHat
```

It says the error,

```
 error: product: non-conformant arguments (op1 is 131072x1, op2 is 128000x1)
```

Even-though I've tried adding the operator '.' i still get the error..

Got any idea why this error occurs?

The total piece of code:

```
[samples,samplingRate] = audioread('car.wav')
dt=1/samplingRate
sampleLength=length(samples)
duration = sampleLength/samplingRate
time = 0:dt:duration #time vector
n=length(time)

%disp("sampling Rate"+Fs)

fHat = fft(samples, n)
%psd = periodogram (fHat)
PSD = periodogram (fHat)
indices = PSD<0.01 #Find all freqs with large power
PSDClean1 = PSD.*indices #find out all others(While there are 0s, PSDs which are there will be 0 from indices vector)
fHatNoisy  = fHat.*indices #Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
```

**UPDATE: It was because the two arrays, fHat and indices are not equal length, that is the reason why i suspect the error occurs. Trying to figure out why fft() returns a different size of an array than the PSD = fHat * conj(fHat)/n**

More Information about PSD, N, their lengths etc:
[image: More Information about PSD, N, their lengths etc]

**[ANSWER]Update 2, Calculating PSD for DFT/FFT:**

```
pkg load signal;

[samples,samplingRate] = audioread('car.wav')

dt=1/samplingRate

sampleLength=length(samples)

n = length(samples);          % number of samples
frequencyRange = (0:n-1)*(samplingRate/n);     % frequency range
fHat = fft(samples)
power = abs(fHat).^2/n;    % power of the DFT

plot(frequencyRange,power)
xlabel('Frequency')
ylabel('Power')
```

Comment: In the code you have the other order of operands `op1` and `op2`, so one of them got to the next power of 2, 131072, as in classical fft

Comment: @kikon Im sorry im a bit new to this domain. Yes that is the same issue in my mind occurring, why FFT returns a different size of an array than the PSD... Sorry for asking silly questions, thank you for supporting.

Comment: You should make it clear: display the values of `sampleLength`,`n` as well as the lengths of `fHat` and `PSD`. I mean display them in your code, but also for us here to see :)

Comment: You should read the documentation. `periodogram` returns a vector of different length than the input: “The number of points, nfft, in the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is the maximum of 256 or the next power of two greater than the signal length.” https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html

Comment: In any case, even if you could do this multiplication, `fHat.*indices` makes no sense because their indices mean different things. One if the FFT of the other.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks a lot for the references, on the way looking to it... aah.. i was using it in the python, so i was just converting this to matlab code actually.. thanks a lot for your support !

Comment: So it's clear - the length of PSD is a power of 2. But you should consider @CrisLuengo's more substantial observation that the multiplication formula doesn't make sense since the two vectors are in different spaces - check the formulae you are using (maybe `PSD` should have been the periodogram of `samples` rather then `fHat` so they are both in the frequency space?)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi Could you please validate the new code that i updated in my question(as 'Update 2, Calculating PSD for DFT/FFT:'). I believe now i got the PSD for my DFT correctly, but instead of using conjugate formula, in this the absolute is used..